# Microsoft Office 2010 Basic Authentication when Opening Files on Windows 2008

Tags: sharepoint, ssl, ms-office

I'm setting up a demo machine with Office and I want to be able to open an Office file using Sharepoint protocol.  It seems like in Office 2010 that only SSL connections are allowed.

For this machine, I don't want to have to set up SSL.

[This Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2123563) describes a workaround and how to configure it to use Basic Authentication, but it doesn't apply to Windows 2008.  The Mr Fixit app fails because it doesn't work on Windows 2008 and the manual fixit doesn't apply.

This registry key doesn't exist in Windows 2008:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient
```

How can I enable Basic Authentication for Office 2010 on Windows 2008?
Create the above registry key?  The description in the fixit makes it sound like it should already exist on those other Windows operating systems.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349797(v=ws.10).aspx Says that the setting can be modified for 08. Perhaps you need to install the Desktop Experience feature for the WebDAV client service? http://www.windowstipspage.com/2010/02/what-is-webclient-service.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the `WebClient` key is missing it sounds like the WebDAV client is not installed.

A quick Google search yielded [this](http://www.windowstipspage.com/2010/02/what-is-webclient-service.html):

> **On my Windows server 2008 system web client service is missing. Why so?**
>
> In Server 2008 edition, default setup does not have web client service. You need to install Desktop experience package to add web client service.